# Selecting 1 From Each Group

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a SQLite table representing a music library called `songs`

it looks something like this (there are many more columns, I am simplifying)

```
 title  |  album  |  artist
 -------|---------|----------
 a song | an album| an artist
```

I am trying to select a list of all albums. Now, on first thought, `SELECT DISTINCT album FROM songs` should work. HOWEVER, this fails if, for example, 2 artists have an album with the same title. Really what I want, is to go through each artist and select 1 of each album therein.

How might I do this?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT artist, album...

Comment: yes, that works, however I need JUST the albums. So is there some easy way to then output just the album column? (this is within some c++ code, not just for visual display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT album 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT album, artist
  FROM songs
)
```